# trouble with Oracle Sun SAS 6GB/s pci-e drivers

Tags: oracle, sas, drivers, lto

I got a new card for my server, a Sun SAS card (SG-XPCIESAS-GEN2-Z), and now I cannot get it to work. I tried many LSI drivers, many Adaptec drivers, but none work, some even crash.

Card P/N is 7056272 and from what I know it uses a standard PM8001c chip.

I saw online that linux works fine with the general pm80xx drivers, but I wanted to use it with a W10 pro machine and no luck there.

I tried contacting Oracle, but dead end there, they won't do anything since I'm not in any registered firm etc.

I need the card as it has full 6GB/s sas external ports, that my backup tape library LTO frive uses.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get those drivers? Card is new, and better than my old one, but right now it's as usefull as a paperweight can be.

Comment: Did you check for drivers on the CD?

Comment: I havent got the cd as this was a spare unit from some company, never used and sold as new